# How to filter Django's CommaSeparatedIntegerField

Tags: django, django-models, filter, field

Assume a model

```
class Foo(models.Model):
    bar = models.CommaSeparatedIntegerField('Filter Me!')
```

The content of the `bar` could look like, e.g., `12,35,67,142`.

I want to query all `Foo`s, that have a `42` in `bar`:

```
all_42_foos = Foo.objects.filter(bar__contains="42")
```

which doesn't give the correct result, since `CommaSeparatedIntegerField` inherits from `CharField` and the filter evaluation uses the string content of the field (matching the above example with `142`, too).

How can I hav a filter, that does a `.split(",")` on the `bar` field before it checks for the `42`? I really don't want `bar` to become a `ManyToMany`, since it'd be a terrible overhead.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

What about something like:

```
from django.db.models import Q

all_42_foos = Foo.objects.filter( Q(bar__startswith='42,') | Q(bar__endswith=',42') | Q(bar__contains=',42,') | Q(bar__exact='42') )
```

While it's a bit of a verbose query, I think something along those lines will be the only way to get what you're looking for. It's probably worth turning that into a separate function along the lines of

```
def all_x_foos(x):
    return Foo.objects.filter( Q(bar__startswith=x+',') | Q(bar__endswith=','+x) | Q(bar__contains=',{0},'.format(x)) | Q(bar__exact=x) )
```

Out of curiosity, have you checked the actual performance of your app w/ both the many-to-many way, and the pseudo-many-to-many method you're describing?

Comment: Thanks! Yes it is verbose, but it does the job. One remark: One has to test for an exact `42,`, too (trailing comma), since that's valid, too for this field.

Answer (score 0):

This answer is an extension of @desfido 's answer.Basically decoupling the object type from the function filtering the CommaSeperatedInteger Field.Turns out this solution is faster than using a regex to find the correct value.I used this regex.

```
_regex = r"(^|(\d*,)+)(%s)((,\d*)+|$)" %('|'.join(_ids))
```

If you want to search for multiple values inside the comma seperated value,one can call the function given below in a loop

This keyword arguments of this function are:-

cs_field_name will be the name of the comma seperated integer field.

x will be the integer to be searched.

It returns a Q object,which can then be combined and used for filtering

```
def search_comma_seperated_field(cs_field_name,x):
    startswith_key = cs_field_name + "__startswith"
    endswith_key = cs_field_name + "__endswith"
    contains_key = cs_field_name + "__contains"
    exact_key = cs_field_name + "__exact"
    return Q(**{startswith_key : x+','}) | \
                                     Q(**{endswith_key:','+x}) |\
                                     Q(**{contains_key : ',{0},'.format(x)}) |\
                                     Q(**{exact_key:x})
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also write it in one regular expression:

```
all_42_foos = Foo.objects.filter(bar__regex=u'^42,|,42,|,42$|^42$')
```

or

```
bar_number = 42
bar_regex = r'^{0},|,{0},|,{0}$|^{0}$'.format(bar_number)
all_42_foos = Foo.objects.filter(bar__regex=bar_regex)
```